# Alternative of system() in c Linux to execute a terminal command on linux

Tags: c, linux, misra

I want to execute a terminal command of Linux in a C program. Currently I am using `system()` function but I want to use any other as the `system()` function is banned as per MISRA.

For example, how can I replace

```
system("hwclock --systohc --utc");
```

Comment: Are you sure that MISRA allows anything even *similar* to `system`? Executing arbitrary code is inherently unsafe.

Comment: Actually when I tried for MISRA compliance of my code than it gives error that system() is a banned function. I am not sure whether MISRA allos anything similar to system.

Comment: If you **really** need to use a call to system() and you understand all the implications that go with that decision, raise a project deviation (see the early chapters of the book) and get your hierarchy to approve it.

Comment: `execve()` should be legal. And the `posix_spawn` family of functions gives you plenty of higher-level equivalent choices -- the important thing with all of them is that you're invoking an explicit argv array, **not** a string that's parsed by a shell; too many people generate strings for shells to parse via simple concatenation and open themselves up to injection attacks.

Comment: @Andrew, ...I can't conceive of a valid reason to use `system()` -- not one. Even if you need a shell, you can still `posix_spawn()` `string[][]("sh", "-c", "...script here...", "sh", "first argument", "second argument")`, and thus pass your parameters out-of-band from your code (substituting parameters into code through string concatenation being the #1 way folks using `system()` shoot themselves and their users in the foot by creating shell injection vulnerabilities).

Comment: I would agree with you Charles, except `posix_spawn()` is not universally available. I would be interested in seeing a valid use case for a deviation to this Rule!

Answer (score 5):

First you can use `fork()` to create a child process, then in the child process, you can call `exec()` to execute command what you want.
There is a simple example:

```
$ chmod u+x command.sh 
$ cat command.sh  
#!/usr/bin/env bash   
ls -l
```

`test.c`:

```
#include<unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
  execl("./command.sh","command.sh",(char*)0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this add to Sourav Ghosh's answer, which was posted about half an hour before yours?

Comment: @KeithThompson: this one doesn't recommend `popen()`, which has the same problems as `system()`

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) and then look up for [`exec()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) family of functions.

Alternatively, you may want to have a look at [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) also.

Comment: `popen()` has the same security problems that cause `system()` to be banned. Any auditor who flags `system()` will object to `popen()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question. My understanding of MISRA C is that it provides guidelines for the use of the C language in critical systems. But the C language standard library, which includes the `system` function, is merely a small piece of the sum total of library code typically used in modern applications -- often even in embedded systems.

I've never developed an application to MISRA standards, and I've only been able to find a slightly older (from 2004) version of the MISRA guidelines. From what I can tell, MISRA is silent about the use of POSIX library functions, which you are typically going to have available on any kind of Linux-based system. If MISRA really is silent about POSIX library functions, then it stands to reason that any functions in the POSIX library should be unrestricted. That would include `fork`, `exec`, and `popen` which are all defined by POSIX, not by the C language standard. Of the three, `popen` is probably most similar in functionality/interface to the C `system` function.

That said, you may want to ask yourself why MISRA C restricts the use of the `system` function and whether or not the same rationale applies to the use of the above three functions as well.

Comment: The rationale of MISRA is that `system()` contains too many forms of undefined and impl.defined behavior to be trusted. Also note that MISRA can be used outside mission-critical software, as a general coding standard, although it is biased towards embedded systems. MISRA doesn't care about POSIX since it is only concerned about standard C. Also, it is rare to use a POSIX OS for embedded systems, and even less so in mission-critical systems, for which you'd have to be quite insane to use some desktop OS like Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The letter of MISRA C:2012/2023 Rule 21.21 (previously part of MISRA C:2012 Rule 21.8) is that the `system()` function shall not be used.

The spirit of the Rule is that equivalent functions should not be used either - the rationale for the Rule explains why: executing external features is a major security vulnerability.

If you **really** need to do so, then the correct approach is *deviate* the Rule (with justification and mitigation) rather than trying to find a workaround.

--
See profile for affiliation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fork` + `exec` family of functions is usually the suggested approach and [a simple implementation is straightforward](https://www.percona.com/community-blog/2021/01/04/fork-exec-wait-and-exit/) however what I've found is that it is a mine field of edge cases.

`system()` uses fork + exec internally and just look at [glibc's implementation](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/ba33937be210da5d07f7f01709323743f66011ce/sysdeps/posix/system.c#L101) its source code is huge to deal with all the signal handlers. But signal handlers clearance + restoration must be dealt in a thread safe manner so there's also race condition issues that need to be accounted in multithreaded code, which is why glib's code is so unreadable.

I suggest you use [posix_spawn](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html) instead if available, which is far more user friendly and, unlike `system`, has a safer interface.